# First Time Ajax request getting two url different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

```
var memberURL;
var memberAva;
var memberName;
var members = data.find('.userdata');
for (var j = 0; j < members.length; j++) {
      membername = $(members[j]).find('.username').text();
      memberURL = $(members[j]).find('.username').attr('href');
   }
memberAva = $('#advanced-profile-right img:eq[0]');

$.ajax({
   url:"/viewonline",
   type:"GET",
   data: {memberURL, memberName}, //What should i do here?
   success: function() {
$.ajax({
   url: memberURL,
   type:"GET",
   data: memberAva
   }).done(function() {
    $('.user_info_on').append('<div class="on_name"><a href="' + memberURL + '" title="'+ memberName +'"><img src="' + memberAva + '"/></a></div>');
    }
  });
 });
```

What I am trying to get from the first ajax request is the members URL and the Members name- then on success make another ajax request to the Members URL (each) and get the Members Avatar. Then on done post the data that is retrieved.  Code is not working, and not sure what I should do?

I tried posting on two .get()s though I guess this is the only way? Anyways anyone have suggestions and tips for me?

The .get() that works-

```
 $(function () {
   $.get('/viewonline', function (data) {
     data = $(data);
     var members = data.find('.userdata');
  for (var j = 0; j < members.length; j++) {
       var membername = $(members[j]).find('.username').text();
       var memberURL = $(members[j]).find('.username').attr('href');
      });
  $('.user_info_on').append('<div class="on_name"><a href="' + memberURL + '" title="'+ membername +'"><img src=""/></a></div>'); //In between source of image would be memberAva from the other .get() request.
      }
    }, 'html');
 });
```

Comment: You've got a number of issues here. Firstly, you've got a comma after memberAva, which will cause the JS to break entirely. Secondly, the first $.ajax() call has no closing brace or parenthesis, nor does its success function.

Comment: You've still got the comma after memberAva. I assume your javascript is not running at all, correct?

Comment: Correct, I am using this in Console, since this is my FIRST ajax code and am well to say the least CLUELESS on it lol.

Comment: Updated Jake hope that is what you are talking about

Comment: @EasyBB Most browsers are tolerant of `,` at the end of an object.

Comment: `Code is not working` what error are you getting? I'd start with **one** ajax request -- does that work? And I'd really consider combining this so you only need one GET instead of two.

Comment: @Jasen is dead on here. In fact I'm reluctant to provide answer here because of that reason. There is never a time where I've created two gets in this manner. Makes no sense. Not being agro here instead trying to impress upon you that you need to rethink this.

Comment: @Jasen issue is that there are two different URLs in the process of here. And I will try with one request to see if it works. Like literally I can use .get() and know what I'm doing, which the .get() for the request work separately just not together.

Comment: `data: {memberURL, memberName}` is not valid Javascript syntax. Object literals must be `{ key: value, key:value, ...}`. You're missing the names of the parameters.

Comment: @C.Hazelton what? Barmar yes i know how do I do those, I know object literals and yet not positive on how to place it in the ajax request. {key:memberURL,key:memberName}, and if that is correct is the last append line still correct?

Comment: I will post my .get() code that works for getting the memberURL and the memberName

Comment: Is the 2nd GET on the same domain?

Comment: Yes it is. The first get is on my site to the url viewonline which gets the a href of the usersname. Then the a href will be used for the second get to get their photo. There must be an easier way which I will look into yet I am very unsure of this, and I believe this is the only way.